# How to calculate velocity for automatic kinetic scrolling

Tags: c#, xna, scroll

I'm implementing a circular menu that the user can drag and flick to scroll its menu items horizontally. When the application first starts, I want to run an automatic kinetic scrolling to show the user how the menu behaves - I just set an arbitrary velocity to be decreased by a given friction when calculating the new position of the menu items in the `Update()` method. Assuming I apply a friction of 0.5f, how do I calculate a velocity that lets the menu items stop exactly where they were before I forced the automatic kinetic scrolling?

Comment: The trick to getting this to work is to use a parametric tween (a formula where you plug in the time and get out the position), instead of a physics simulation. Then it's a simple bit of algebra.

Comment: Yes... it works more or less. Since I apply a friction of 0.5f to slow-down, I never reach 0 and I have to force it to stop scrolling, and this results in a unprecise distance.